# DSO Error when trying to Link with boost_timer

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to link a simple program with `boost_timer` using g++. The program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>

void linear_sum(int n);
void quadratic_sum(int n);
void sigmatic_sum(int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int m[5] = {100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000};
  int tmp = 0;

  for(tmp; tmp < 5; tmp++){
    std::cout << "Timing information for linear sum with n = " << m[tmp] << ":\n";
    linear_sum(m[tmp]);

    std::cout << "Timing information for quadratic_sum with n = " << m[tmp] << ":\n";
    quadratic_sum(m[tmp]);

    std::cout << "Timing information for sigmatic_sum with n = " << m[tmp] << ":\n";
  }
}
```

I have attempted to compile the program with:

```
g++ -o a1main a1main.cpp -lboost_timer
```

The `boost_timer` header and library are both within the default compiler search paths. I'm using Slackware 14.2, which comes with boost and the boost compiled libraries out of the box. I am also using the stock compiler that comes with g++. (e.g. It's not a custom built toolchain or anything)

I'm not sure what I'm missing, but I get the following error when I try to compile:

> /usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-slackware-linux/5.3.0/../../../../x86_64-slackware-linux/bin/ld:
>   /tmp/ccRDEN9Q.o: undefined reference to symbol
>   `_ZN5boost6system15system_categoryEv`
>   /usr/lib64/libboost_system.so.1.59.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Thoughts?

(p.s. I looked around for similar problems. There were some, but they were either solved by adding the `-lboost_timer` linker flag, which I've already done, or were solved by changing the order of multiple linker flags owing to linking dependencies. As I'm only linking against this one library, there are no circular dependencies for me to `uncircle`, so to speak. Hence, I'm asking this question here to see if there is something else I can try.)

Comment: I think you need `-lboost_system`.

Comment: Or `-DBOOST_SYSTEM_NO_DEPRECATED`.

Comment: You have to add -lboost_system like @Jonas said

Comment: Ah! Ok, @Jonas. Yep yep, that fixed it. Boneheaded move on my part. xD Thanks.

Comment: @Druid No problem. I have, for good measure, added an answer based on the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `-lboost_system` to your build command. When you use `boost_timer` you may need `boost_system` as well. This also goes for many other boost libraries, but not necessarily all of them.